# Dependency-injecting Laravel's Mailer class

Tags: dependency-injection, laravel, laravel-4

So I've been dependency-injecting all facade-referencing classes into my controller today as seen on Taylor Otwell's latest blog post here:

http://taylorotwell.com/response-dont-use-facades/

The following constructor injects its dependencies properly:

```
public function __construct(
    Illuminate\Session\Store $session,
    Illuminate\Routing\Redirector $redirect,
    Illuminate\View\Environment $view
) {
    ...
}
```

I am using the facade class reference for this:

http://laravel.com/docs/facades#facade-class-reference

However, when I try and inject the mailer class, I get the error "class mailer does not exist".  I am trying like so:

```
public function __construct(
    Illuminate\Session\Store $session, 
    Illuminate\Routing\Redirector $redirect, 
    Illuminate\View\Environment $view, 
    Illuminate\Mail\Mailer $mailer
)
```

The class obviously does exist, and the facade class reference appears to be correct too.  I don't know what could be causing this error.

I'm additionally having the same problem with the Validator class, but I assume the solution would be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Turns out there was a small bug in the framework source.](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3252)